# why data fetching from Redis is very slow on Socket and TCP?

Tags: python, redis

I have `365` sets. Each refers to a day from `2011-01-01` to `2012-01-01`. In each `SET` I have 8000 value. It has 3 to 5 characters at most e.g.: `271`.

When I issue `SMEMBERS` command in python it takes about 17.7 second!

A sample result in `redis-cli`:

```
 $ SMEMBERS prefix:2011-01-01
    1) "2442"
    2) "5483"
    ...
    7999) "7911"
    8000) "42968"
```

In python with Redis **version** = '2.10.3' I use socket rather than `TCP` to get better performance.

`INFO` command gives the below information about server, memory:

```
# Server
redis_version:2.8.19
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:70633d1af7244f5e
redis_mode:standalone
os:Darwin 14.4.0 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:kqueue
gcc_version:4.2.1
process_id:2186
run_id:b12ff3e92969904fcd5050f4b26308be34898512
tcp_port:0
uptime_in_seconds:949
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
lru_clock:1445239
config_file:/usr/local/etc/redis.conf

# Clients
connected_clients:1
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

# Memory
used_memory:172002960
used_memory_human:164.03M
used_memory_rss:217276416
used_memory_peak:216397792
used_memory_peak_human:206.37M
used_memory_lua:35840
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.26
mem_allocator:libc

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:0
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1444284866
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok

# Stats
total_connections_received:3
total_commands_processed:1873
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0
total_net_input_bytes:78549
total_net_output_bytes:53268971
instantaneous_input_kbps:0.00
instantaneous_output_kbps:0.00
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:504
keyspace_misses:1364
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:0

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:0.46
used_cpu_user:3.51
used_cpu_sys_children:0.00
used_cpu_user_children:0.00

# Keyspace
db0:keys=368,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

The code in python I use is as below:

```
unix_socket_path = '/tmp/redis.sock'
redis_client = redis.Redis(unix_socket_path=unix_socket_path)
pipe = redis_client.pipeline()
for date in daily_date_range:
    pipe.smembers('paying:' + date)

redis_result = pipe.execute()
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: SMEMBERS of 8000-element set takes about 60 milliseconds on my laptop (TCP, localhost). Are you talking about one SMEMBERS or 365 SMEMBERS taking 17 seconds?

Comment: 365 SMEMBERS, each with 8000 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do anything wrong, [SMEMBERS](http://redis.io/commands/SMEMBERS) is just that slow for big sets. One call takes only about 50 milliseconds, but you do 365 of them - that's many megabytes of data.

To improve performance, consider the following:

1. Do you really need to read all data for the whole year? Maybe you can achieve your goals without full scan.
2. If you are calculating some aggregates, consider writing a Redis-side Lua script for that, and return only those aggregates.
3. Cache the results. Assuming that this is read-only historical data, 17 seconds is nothing - you just run your algorithm once and then use cached results.

Comment: I used Lua and turned sets into lists and had a better performance. I changed `redis` to `mongo` anddddd voila! It took 0.1 second. So I think redis was not a suitable case for this scenario. +1 for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I used Lua and turned sets into lists and had a better performance. I changed redis to mongo and voila! It took 0.1 second. So I think redis was not a suitable case for this scenario